# Почему выводится первый элемент в цикле

Tags: javascript

Здравствуй.не подскажете, почему выводится первый элемент цикла как undefined

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
    
        type: "GET",        
        url: "./city.json",

        success: function (data) {
                
            var text;

            for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                
                text +=data[i].name + i + '<br/>';
            }
            
            $('#content').html(text);

        },
        error:function(){
            console.log('Error')
        }
    });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="content">Текст</div>
```

Если подключить данный код к json и папкам, все заработает
сам json файл там вида

```
[
    {"id": 1, "name": "Москва"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Воронеж"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "МоскваСтарая"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "Тула"},
    {"id": 5, "name": "МоскваСтановится"}
]
```

http://prntscr.com/ppjn5t

Answer (score 3):

вроде так: var text = ''; а не просто var text;

Comment: Спасибо! Вроде помогло